# Url in section title

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, bookmarks, url

I'm trying to put an url in the title of a subsection in a report. 
I am using the package `hyperref`.
What I am doing is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Matlab code}
\subsection{\nolinkurl{file1.m}}

\end{document}
```

This won't compile as I get the following error:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \@@BOOKMARK.<inserted text>\par\begin{document}
```

Actually, when I compile for the first time, it usually works. But when I try another time, I get that error...

I am using Texmaker and MiKTeX.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Try `\subsection{\texorpdfstring{\nolinkurl{file1.m}}{file1.m}}` which prevents content not allowed for `PDF` strings (as in bookmarks)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Perhaps you could post an answer with that and Rudy could mark it correct? This is a common issue, that could benefit from a clearly-marked answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\texorpdfstring{tex content}{pdf string content}` in order to prevent errors since not any content is allowed in bookmarks (this must be `PDF`  strings)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Matlab code}
\subsection{\texorpdfstring{\nolinkurl{file1.m}}{file1.m}}

\end{document}
```